# Is there a way to move right aligned text only into another cell in excel?

Tags: excel

I have one column in excel that contains the source ip in the first cell then on the next row contains any open ports for that source ip.  for the cells that contain the port number they are all right aligned.  I am trying to find out how I can move all of the port numbers over to the next column called "Ports" in excel.

[image: Excel example here]

Comment: You could use `ISNUMBER` to list all the port numbers

Answer (score 0):

1. Select Cell A1
2. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> *(i.e. Down Arrow)*
3. Release <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and press <kbd>→</kbd> *(i.e. Right Arrow)* twice
4. Go to "Insert" and create a table. (unckeck my table has headers)
5. Add the following text to Cell B2: "=IF(ISNUMBER(A2);"";A2)"
6. Add the following text to Cell C2: "=IF(ISNUMBER(A2);A2;"")"
7. Copy the result of row B and C to another sheet. In paste options you need to select that it only pastes values (thing with numbers).
8. https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2018/11/28/remove-blank-cells-excel/

Image below shows it but it is in German.

[image: Example but my language is German --> WENN is IF and ISTZAHL is ISNUMBER]

Comment: You also could do it wit the help of this: [How to copy special values only](https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2015/07/16/copy-numbers-only-in-excel/) May be the better solution.

Both options can be done as IP adresses are text and not numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way I can think of is using **Goto** feature.

1. First you need to copy the entire list in column A to column B.

   [image]
2. Then, using Goto, select all numbers in column A. To use Goto, select column A then press F5. Then click on `Special`. You will see below dialog box. Tick Constant and Numbers as seen below and press ok.

   [image]
3. After executing step 2, all numbers will be selected as seen below. Press delete.

   [image]
4. Repeat steps for column B. This time, you select Constant and Text. Then delete.

   [image]

There you have it, you've transferred all the port numbers in column B under ports.
 This is assuming all your IP's are text and all your ports are numbers.